# Git clone error: RPC failed - curl 28 Operation too slow

Tags: git, github, curl, git-clone

I am trying to clone the linux kernel, the transfer speed seems perfectly fine, but curl always aborts:

```sh
❯ git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/archlinux/linux
Cloning into 'linux'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 78109, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (78109/78109), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 28 Operation too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 3 seconds
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

I have tried adding or removing `--depth` as well as using a different machine (one using Arch, the other on Ubuntu), same result...

### Diagnostics

#### Setup

Arch Linux

```sh
❯ git --version
git version 2.33.1
❯ curl --version
curl 7.79.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.79.1 OpenSSL/1.1.1l zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.0 libidn2/2.3.2 libpsl/0.21.1 (+libidn2/2.3.0) libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.45.1
Release-Date: 2021-09-22
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd
❯ ldd "$(which curl)"
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcde7df000)
    /usr/lib/libstderred.so (0x00007fbb71615000)
    libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007fbb71541000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbb71520000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbb71354000)
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbb7134d000)
    libnghttp2.so.14 => /usr/lib/libnghttp2.so.14 (0x00007fbb71321000)
    libidn2.so.0 => /usr/lib/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007fbb712fd000)
    libssh2.so.1 => /usr/lib/libssh2.so.1 (0x00007fbb712bc000)
    libpsl.so.5 => /usr/lib/libpsl.so.5 (0x00007fbb712a9000)
    libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007fbb71217000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007fbb70f38000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007fbb70ee3000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /usr/lib/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007fbb70dd2000)
    libbrotlidec.so.1 => /usr/lib/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x00007fbb70dc4000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007fbb70daa000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbb71653000)
    libunistring.so.2 => /usr/lib/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007fbb70c28000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007fbb70b41000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007fbb70b0e000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /usr/lib/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007fbb70b08000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007fbb70af8000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /usr/lib/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007fbb70af1000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /usr/lib/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fbb70ad7000)
    libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /usr/lib/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x00007fbb70ab4000)
```

Speedtest:

```
curl -o /dev/null http://speedtest.tele2.net/100MB.zip  0,16s user 0,57s system 5% cpu 14,183 total
```

#### Retry

On a new day, it now gets a little further:

```sh
❯ git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/archlinux/linux
Cloning into 'linux'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 78109, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (78109/78109), done.
remote: Compressing objects:  36% (26365/73234)
```

but still aborts whenever the transfer slows down for a few seconds:

```sh
❯ git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/archlinux/linux
Cloning into 'linux'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 78109, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (78109/78109), done.
remote: Compressing objects:  36% (26365/73234)
```

The solution seems to be to pass `--speed-time` to `curl` via `git`,
which I have no idea how to do even after looking at all git man pages related to configuration I could find.

Comment: you say "transfer speed is perfectly fine", but i have my doubts. what do you get from `time git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/archlinux/linux` ?  and what do you get from `time curl -o /dev/null http://speedtest.tele2.net/100MB.zip` ?

Comment: The first command errors out and thus shows nothing. Download speed is not an issue.
I suspect that, since the remote first compresses the objects and sends almost no data, `curl` gets impatient. So I guess the question is rather how I can advise curl to be more patient.

Comment: i don't think it's a compression issue, because `time git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/archlinux/linux` works fine for me: https://i.imgur.com/ujZoCQ4.png

Comment: I added some more info

Comment: ... that curl log indicates you downloaded 100MB in the span of 0.16 seconds.. you're either on a 5Gigabit+ connection, or the connection broke.. what do you get from doing the same with `curl -v --progress-bar` ? also, are you really on a 5Gbit-or-faster internet connection?

Comment: No, I downloaded them in 14 seconds, you picked out the time the CPU was engaged ;)

Comment: any chance your libcurl is compiled with GnuTLS? what do you get from `ldd "$(which curl)"`

Comment: no idea, added - thanks for looking into this with me :)

Comment: it's not GnuTLS, it's OpenSSL, i've seen GnuTLS cause similar issues (where the solution ended up being "replace GnuTLS with OpenSSL and we're good to go", but OpenSSL should work fine)

 - this is a really weird issue, i'm kindof out of ideas. if i was really determined to figure this out, my next move would probably be to set up Fiddler Proxy Classic as a MITM/system-proxy with a fake SSL/TLS cert (Fiddler makes it really easy to make a fake SSL cert, installable system-wide), and have git clone it through Fiddler, maybe Fiddler can see what's taking so long/what's going on...

Comment: Well, it happens on Ubuntu, Debian and Arch in different locations, so I doubt it is something that specific. It always works fine until the transfer slows down a little for a few seconds and curl aborts.

Comment: why can't I simply tell curl via git to allow for more than 3 seconds until timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of frustration it became apparent that the problem was once again in front of the computer. The following option in my git config was the culprit:

```
[http]
    lowSpeedLimit = 1000
    lowSpeedTime = 3
```

Raising the values fixed it.